# Magento2 Apply Patches

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, security, patches

I have some customers that use some "older" Magento 2 versions, like for example 2.3.4.
I would like to keep the store updated with the latest security patches but without doing a full Magento 2 upgrade.

How can I install the latest security patch (2.3.7-p1) on my 2.3.4 version?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to applied 2.3.7-p1 patch to 2.3.4. You need to upgrade your Magento version to 2.3.7-p1.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply them by yourself with
git apply ./path/to/patch

It is not recommended and can lead to big problems. You have to understand the code of the patch and evaluate it case by case.